# How to query table with partial key values

Tags: go, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am working with hyperledger (v0.6) tables and have a structure as follows;

```
var columnDefsTableOne []*shim.ColumnDefinition
columnOneTableOneDef := shim.ColumnDefinition{Name: "RefNum",
    Type: shim.ColumnDefinition_STRING, Key: true}
columnTwoTableOneDef := shim.ColumnDefinition{Name: "Amount",
    Type: shim.ColumnDefinition_STRING, Key: false}
columnThreeTableOneDef := shim.ColumnDefinition{Name: "Status",
    Type: shim.ColumnDefinition_STRING, Key: true}
columnDefsTableOne = append(columnDefsTableOne, &columnOneTableOneDef)
columnDefsTableOne = append(columnDefsTableOne, &columnTwoTableOneDef)
columnDefsTableOne = append(columnDefsTableOne, &columnThreeTableOneDef)
    return stub.CreateTable("Recon", columnDefsTableOne)
```

When I query the table with *RefNum* only or both *RefNum* & *Status*, the row is returned. But if I try to query on the basis of *Status* only, nothing is returned. Is there any way to achieve this?

Below is the query code

```
if len(args) < 1 {
    return nil, errors.New("Function failed. Must include at least key values")
}

var columns []shim.Column

col1Val := args[0]
col1 := shim.Column{Value: &shim.Column_String_{String_: col1Val}}
columns = append(columns, col1)

if len(args) > 1 {
    col2Val := args[1]
    col2 := shim.Column{Value: &shim.Column_String_{String_: col2Val}}
    columns = append(columns, col2)
}

rowChannel, err := stub.GetRows("Recon", columns)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Operation failed. %s", err)
}

var rows []shim.Row
for {
    select {
    case row, ok := <-rowChannel:
        if !ok {
            rowChannel = nil
        } else {
            rows = append(rows, row)
        }
    }
    if rowChannel == nil {
        break
    }
}

jsonRows, err := json.Marshal(rows)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Operation failed. Error marshaling JSON: %s", err)
}

return jsonRows, nil
```

Answer (score 1):

The row keys are not true keys in the sense of a relational database. Internally, range queries are utilized against the concatenated set of keys.  Therefore, the keys in the query must be provided in the same order as they were modeled.

The chaincode APIs have been updated in Fabric v1.0 to make the behavior more intuitive.  In v1.0 you can model a composite key and then query on a subset of the keys (again, in the order that they were modeled).

To query on different combinations of keys, you would have to model each unique combination that you'd like to query on.  Think of these as simple indexes.

In v1.0 you can also model your data as JSON and utilize CouchDB as the state database.  In this case you can directly query on any field of the JSON.

There is an example of both data patterns in the marbles02 chaincode here:

```
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/examples/chaincode/go/marbles02/marbles_chaincode.go.
```